# BreezeJS mixing cache and server data unexpectedly

Tags: breeze

I'm having a weird (or at least unexpected) problem with Breeze. I have an EF back-end view model to which I send some parameters and it returns some data. I use the `withParameters` option to do this. The back-end does a lot of `Include`s and projection and returns the data I want to display in a set of custom view model entities (i.e., not database entities). One of the parameters is a list of keys for which I want to display data.

The keys identify which children of the parent entities I want to retrieve, though I am retrieving a list of parents (e.g. keys `[1,2]` mean it should get all `Parent` entities with a `Children` list property that themselves have a `ToyId` property that has a value in keys and those `Child` entites). In other words, the structure is like `Parent.Child[]` and `Child.ToyId` and I want to get parents with children that have certain toys and those children themselves (but not other children). Both parent and child sets are large so I do this in SQL via EF (which was an adventure in itself).

Anyway, the problem happens after I select two keys and get the data and then de-select one of the keys. The first query, getting the data for two keys, works as expected. On the second `executeQuery`'s callback, I get the *same data as the previous query*, meaning it's as if I never de-selected the key. I've verified that Breeze hits the back-end with the correct `keys` parameter value and the back-end returns *just* the data I want, but it seems that Breeze is ignoring the data from the back-end or performing a union on the result set from the back-end and its cached entities (for both keys) and sending that union as `results` into the callback instead of just what the server returned. Is this expected behavior? Unfortunately everything is written this way. We (working on this, our first project using Breeze) all assumed it would only return what the server sent when not using `executeQueryLocally`, so it will be a big deal to refactor. Sigh.

I tried some `where` predicates which didn't work and don't see how projecting on the Breeze side would help either. I thought maybe it saw the query as identical so it returned cached data as a shortcut, so I added a `where('Parent.Children', 'any', 'ToyId', 'in', keys)`, but that didn't work, it still brings in the de-selected results.

The only way I've found to get around this is via `queryManager.clear()` before I make any of the queries, and I suspect doing a `noTracking` query might work also (albeit without actual entity objects). I thought about converting the `keys` parameter into a `where` filter and sourcing it from there instead of the `keys` parameter, in case that would tell Breeze to only show the back-end data.

Is there a "correct" way of getting back only the data the server sends in the callback?

("The callback" meaning the function passed into `executeQuery.then(...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, Breeze merges the query results into the cache before calling your callback method.  This means that, in the callback, a parent entity will have **all** of its children that exist in the cache.

The array of entities returned by the query is available in the `retrievedEntities` property of the saveResult object returned in the callback.  You can use this to determine which children were returned from the query.

```
entityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
    var parents = data.results;
    var ret = data.retrievedEntities;
    //... filter ret to get the children
    //... update viewmodel with children
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately retrievedEntities is flat and doesn't preserve the hierarchy in the original results, which means testing for types, more refactoring, or worse restructuring it, which is unfortunate. Thanks for mentioning it, though, this seems to be the only offering from Breeze for this data, currently. Maybe we can hack it to expose a property for the pre-merged verbatim results.

Comment: Yes, retrievedEntities is flat.  Entities get put into the hierarchy as part of merging into the cache, which is what you don't want.  You'll have to create a utility function to get the children of a given parent from the retrievedEntities.